# User removed content from question

Tags: discussion, support, questions, edits, specific-edit

I was now upvoting questions when stumbled across a very peculiar question with a behaviour never seen up to this point.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61400069/5675325), OP edited the content of the question to

> content has been removed. sorry.

Not sure how to deal with it but I don't see value in having such question then. Did some research through Google using similar to the terms `user removed content from question stack` but couldn't find anything that was similar to it.

How should one proceed in this case?

Comment: I rolled back that totally invalid edit. If the user tries to *vandalize* it again feel free to flag that post for moderator attention.

Comment: Side note: for whatever reasons "vandalize" and "deface" are the words used to describe that "user removed content" on meta... As result finding a duplicate requires that special knowledge...

Comment: As it happens, [last month](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60644860/revisions) I reverted a similarly destructive edit (removing the code after "this is my code") by that same user. Someone wasn't getting the message – hopefully your comment will now make it clear.

Comment: This will be a good duplicate to keep so the title will match future searches.